# How can I get the last agent which was inside delay block in AnyLogic?

Tags: anylogic

I would like to get the the agent which has just left the delay-block. I do not want to use on at exit if it is not necessary. So basically I want to use on exit and it gives back the agent which just left.
So for example the console says: "The agent that just left is ....", given that there is a System.out..... in the on exit.

I do not have a good idea sadly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Create a variable `lastAgentLeft` of the type that your agents actually are (assume `MyAgent` here)
2. in the `Delay`'s "on at exit" code box, write `lastAgentLeft = agent;`

That's it. Now you can access the last agent always (by accessing that variable). Just make sure to test if any agent has actually left, for example by testing `if (lastAgentLeft != null)` (or fold that into a getter function)